# Can I manipulate the current iteration of the collection being currently iterated over?

Tags: arrays, ruby, iterator, enumerator

Say I have a collection of `@lines`, and I want to iterate over it, but I want to manipulate how it is iterated over based on the contents of the collection, how do I do that?

i.e. something like this:

```
@lines.each_with_index do |line, index|
   if (index % 3 = 0)
      jump_to index == next_multiple_of_3
   end
end
```

So what that may look like is something like this:

```
Element | Index
a       | 1
b       | 2
c       | 3
f       | 6
g       | 7
h       | 8
i       | 9
l       | 12
```

How can I do that?

**Edit 1**

Note that, as I explained in a comment below, I don't necessarily always want to jump to a specific multiple. Basically, I would want to jump to some arbitrary index that is determined by something that happens within the current iteration.

So the first go around, it could jump `3` indices up, but then the next time it jumps `7` indices up, then for the next 5 times it jumps by `1` like normal, then it jumps by `2` indices up.

The only constant is that the way to determine how it progresses through the original iteration is based on something that happens within the block of the current iteration.

Comment: @sschmeck, `[1,2,3].method(:step) #Name error: undefined method 'step' for class 'Array'`.

Comment: shouldn't it be `if (index % 3 == 0)` instead of `if (index % 3 = 0)`

Comment: The concrete intention is that I don't necessarily always want to jump to a specific multiple. Basically, I would want to jump to some arbitrary index that is determined by something that happens within the current iteration. So the first go around, it could jump `3` indices up, but then the next time it jumps `7` indices up, then for the next 5 times it jumps by 1 like normal, then it jumps by `2` indices up. But the only constant is that the way to determine how it progresses through the original iteration is based on something that happens within the block of the current iteration.

Comment: @marcamillion do you always skip elements or could you also "jump back"?

Comment: @Stefan Great question. Always jump forward, aka...skip elements. Never "jump back".

Comment: Use a `while` loop and manage the index yourself. Something we were discouraging people from doing for ages. But this is the one case where it's appropriate. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Can you add an answer to reflect your suggestion. I really like where you are going with this.

Comment: @marcamillion is `@lines` is an arbitrary collection or an array?

Comment: @Stefan It is an array...basically it is a string that looks like this: `@lines = commit.body.lines`, which is a Ruby method on a string that converts it to an array.

Comment: I may be missing something here, but what's wrong with `next if condition_not_applicable?`?

Comment: @fylooi: if you want to jump _several_ positions at once, you'd need to track this on each iteration. (is the jump over yet?). This requires more code.

Comment: @CarySwovelandYou are right, I mixed up Enumerable with Range. My suggestion makes no sense here. There I deleted it. Thanks.

Comment: Some more logic is needed. Otherwise, why shouldn't it jump from 6 to 9?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a while loop and manage the index yourself. We were discouraging people from doing this for ages. But this is the one case where it's appropriate. :)

```
idx = 0
while idx < @lines.length
  line = @lines[idx]
  idx += condition ? x : y # or whatever logic you have
end
```

This, of course, assumes that `@lines` is capable of random access. If it's not, make it an array.

Comment: It's precisely because I took it out of my mind, which is why I never even thought about it, before you pointed it out.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use this logic multiple times, you might want to define an Enumerable method :

```
module Enumerable
  def skip
    Enumerator.new do |yielder|
      skip_count = 0
      each_with_index do |object, index|
        if skip_count > 0
          skip_count -= 1
        else
          yielder << object
          skip_count = yield(object, index) || 0
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You can use it on any `Enumerable`, and you can specify the number of elements that should be skipped, depending on the current element and index.

For your example, you want to skip 2 elements (e.g. 4 and 5), every 6 elements. There's an offet though, you want to skip the elements after `index = 2` (Ruby indices are 0-based) :

```
puts ('a'..'z').skip{ |_, index| 2 if (index - 2) % 6 == 0 }.take(8)
# a
# b
# c
# f
# g
# h
# i
# l
```

Answer (score 1):

One might do it using the temporary accumulator:

```
@lines = (1..12).map(&:to_s)
JUMP_BY = 3
@lines.each.with_index.reduce(0) do |acc, (line, index)|
  next acc unless index == acc

  puts "line: #{line}"
  q, mod = index.divmod(JUMP_BY)
  (mod == JUMP_BY - 1) && (q % 2).zero? ? \
    (q + 2) * JUMP_BY - 1 : index + 1 # next 
end
#⇒ line: 1
#  line: 2
#  line: 3
#  line: 6
#  line: 7
#  line: 8
#  line: 9
#  line: 12
```

By making `JUMP_BY` a method, one might achieve as complicated decisions as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You are making it more complicated than necessary. You don't need to jump in iteration. Just ignore the task when the condition is (un)satisfied, and go to the next iteration.

```
@lines.each_with_index do |line, index|
  next if index % 3 == 0
  ... # do the contentful things
end
```

Comment: The problem is that 3 `next`s might be needed.

Comment: Exactly @EricDuminil. That's the core issue. Don't just assume that the iteration is just by 1, it could be by 5 or 7.

Answer (score 1):

By using next on a Enumerator you can jump x steps

```
def walk
    e = ('a'..'z').each
    while e.any?
        rand(5).times{e.next}
        puts e.peek
    end
rescue StopIteration => e
end
```

Comment: `e.any?` check is quite redundant in presence of `StopIteration` handling. Can be simple `loop do`.